# Assign rank number to rows with possible duplicates based on date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have a following table which stores bids

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ lot_id     ║  user_id  ║         date         ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬══════════════════════╣
║ 123        ║ 9001      ║ 2017-08-09 14:33:55  ║
║ 123        ║ 9005      ║ 2017-08-09 14:33:55  ║
║ 123        ║ 9001      ║ 2017-08-09 14:44:55  ║
║ 124        ║ 8012      ║ 2017-08-09 14:55:55  ║
║ 124        ║ 9001      ║ 2017-08-09 14:55:55  ║
║ 124        ║ 9076      ║ 2017-08-09 14:66:55  ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

The idea is not to show user_id (due to security reasons), but instead showing user ordinal (sequential?) number which depends on the time he placed the bid.
I need a query which will return me `first bidder`, `second bidder`, `N bidder` according to the `date`.

This will be very inefficient doing it in PHP.

P.S. It was kind of difficult to formulate the problem, so any suggestions in question title are welcome.

**UPDATE**
Row number will not work. If the same user makes multiple bids the number should be the same. For example, if same user has made first bid an 10th bid it should display `first bidder`

Comment: @RyanWilson, I have updated the question. My question is different

Comment: Does the counting need to reset for each lot?

Comment: @SalmanA, no need for this because I will only use this query for specific lots (where lot_id=123)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a sub-query to assign a number to each user_id, based on the date.

Then join that sub-query to the bids table and use that bidder's number.

**Example:**

```
-- Sample data
create table bidstable (lot_id int, user_id int, `date` datetime);
insert into bidstable (lot_id, user_id, `date`) values
(123,9001,'2017-08-09 14:33:55'),
(123,9005,'2017-08-09 14:33:55'),
(123,9001,'2017-08-09 14:44:55'),
(124,8012,'2017-08-09 14:55:55'),
(124,9001,'2017-08-09 14:55:55'),
(124,9076,'2017-08-09 14:56:55');

SELECT lot_id, concat('bidder ', n) as bidder, `date`
FROM bidstable AS bids
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, @n := @n + 1 as n
  FROM bidstable
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @n := 0) vars
  GROUP BY user_id
  ORDER BY MIN(`date`), user_id
) AS bidders ON bidders.user_id = bids.user_id
ORDER BY `date`;
```

SQL Fiddle test [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/672133/3/0)

Comment: Side-note. It doesn't generate bidder names as 'First Bidder', 'Second Bidder'.  Because I think it's just to troublesome to translate those numbers to words.

Comment: No problem, I will use something like "Bidder #1". Thank you for your time!

Comment: @DanielG Indeed, that hashtag does make it look better. :) Btw, in a solution for MySql 8.x, by using the ROW_NUMBER window function, there might not even be a need for a sub-query. Probably. Hmm, on second thought, never mind, it might be more tricky to do it that way after all.

Answer (score 1):

This is an inefficient, brute-force solution to rank users by (earliest) time. The plus side is that it does not use user variables or nested ORDER BY which could produce [unexpected results](https://mysqlserverteam.com/row-numbering-ranking-how-to-use-less-user-variables-in-mysql-queries/):

```
SELECT bids.lot_id, CONCAT('Bidder ', ranks.rank, ' (', bids.user_id, ')'), bids.date
FROM bids
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT curr.user_id, COUNT(prev.user_id) + 1 AS rank
    FROM (
        SELECT user_id, MIN(DATE) AS min_date
        FROM bids
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) AS curr
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT user_id, MIN(DATE) AS min_date
        FROM bids
        GROUP BY user_id
    ) AS prev ON prev.min_date < curr.min_date
    GROUP BY curr.user_id
) AS ranks ON bids.user_id = ranks.user_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db218c/21)